# freeradius apache2/php authorization - ubuntu 5.15

Tags: php, apache2, freeradius, radius

my situation:

I have two severs, a apache2 webserver and a freeradius-server. The webserver does authenticates himself against the radius. For this, I use the **libapache2-mod-auth-radius** packet.

Now where the authenticates works, I want to a authorization.

Based on the building of the website, would it be perfect, if the authorization work over var's. Simple role identifiers. - Resp. this is my currently approach.

```php
// The example should only show, why I want to work by my authorization with variables.

//Role1
   if(in_array("Role1", $Roles, true)){
      ?> <center>
      <from method="post">
      <button...

//Role2
   if(in_array("Role2", $Roles, true)){
      ?> <center>
      <from method="post">
      <button...
```

My question, have anyone a idea or a solution what i can do? I want to authenticate and authoricate my webserver, in the best case without rebuilding everything.

Sry for my english. Its late and I'm not so great.

Thanks for help.

---

I tried this over the Freeradius > User > Reply-Message attribute, but the message didn't reach the webserver, despite of authentication with success. I have searched the relevant logs.

```
admin Cleartext-Password := "Secret"
      Reply-Message = "Role"
```

On the radius server himself, the reply-message works. But not on the webserver, I can't find it.

```
Radiusserver: 
   admin@radiusserver:~$ radtest admin Secret localhost 0 testing123
   Sent Access-Request Id 215 from 0.0.0.0:58426 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 75
       User-Name = "admin"
       User-Password = "Secret"
       NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.1.1
       NAS-Port = 0
       Message-Authenticator = 0x00
       Cleartext-Password = "Secret"
   Received Access-Accept Id 215 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:58426 length 31
       Reply-Message = "Role"

Webserver
   azubi@webserver:~$ cat /var/log/apache2/access.log
   172.31.31.2 - admin [15/Mar/2023:18:52:22 +0000] "GET /website/website.php       
   HTTP/1.1" 200 1077 "https://x.x.x.x/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64;rv:109.0)    
   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0"

   admin@webserver:~$ journalctl | grep role
```

It doesn't help.